# Reading Oracle CLOB data from ODBC reader is super slow

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc

We're downloading data from an Oracle database using C# and .Net 4.5.

`values[]` is an object array;
reader is the ODBC reader with an open connection to the Oracle database table with CLOB data.

Here's the relevant code:

```
if (reader.Read())
{   //Download and save the values
    for (int x = 0; x < reader.FieldCount; x++)
    {   //Populate all the values
        values[x] = reader[x];  //this line seems to cause execution to hang
    }
    //
    //blah blah blah
    //
}
```

The C# code seems to hang on the line `values[x] = reader[x];`.

We're assigning every column in the row read to a special object array because we need to do separate stuff on that data later, and not have to worry about the data type at the moment.

The problem lies that when a table is hit with an Oracle CLOB data column that's big ( > 28,000 ), that line never seems to complete.

If we eliminate the CLOB column from what the odbc reader reads, everything works perfectly.

Questions:

1. Why would this be? Shouldn't the array assignment be relatively quick?
2. What are some possible work arounds so we can keep the CLOB columns in the data downloaded? We
   need to keep the ODBC reader as a generic ODBC reader (and not made Oracle specific).

The application is compiled and must remain 32-bit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a really compelling reason to use ODBC, you are far better off using ODP.net or managed ODP.net.  While I can't say with 100% certainty that ODBC is your issue, I can tell you I have used .NET with LOBs numerous times without issue, using ODP.net.  I can also tell you that the Microsoft driver for Oracle (depricated) caused countless mystery issues, most of them arround performance.  For example, query 1 works fine, but replacing a literal with a bind variable results in a 15 second performance delay on the execute.  Using ODP.net, the delay goes away.  My guess is that ODBC may have similar mystery issues.

ODP.net (or DevArt dotConnect) are the only two tools I know of that enable .NET to leverage the OCI, which has great features like bulk inserts and updates.  It's possible that OCI has a better way of dealing with large LOBs.  Is there a compelling reason you have to use ODBC?

Comment: Thanks @Hambone. The compelling reason we are using ODBC is because this application can be run against numerous databases, and we didn't want to have to specifically code for each one. For instance, off the top of my head this app can query SQL Server, Oracle, a legacy database using 32-bit ODBC Tibco drivers, and a PostGre database. The code, as it stands, works for everything except (recently) the Oracle CLOB data. Given limited resources, it would be great to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I'm going to make this as the answer for now. Unfortunately we don't have the time/resources at the moment to test this theory and write code specifically using the ODP stuff, but if we ever do hopefully I'll remember to come back and update this. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It the type CLOB which is the problem!
cast it to `varchar` and the performance is ok:

change

```
select clob from table
```

to 2 selects

```
select DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(clob,4000,1) from table where length(clob)<= 4000;
select clob from table where length(clob)> 4000;
```

It's easy to verify - the performance is slow for small clob columns as weel, but casting the to varchar solves the problem!

The problem is that every single CLOB column fetch issues 2 extra net roundtrips from the client to the server!

Normally you'll have one net roundtrip for several rows

Answer (score 0):

Add LONGDATACOMPAT=1; on your string connection:

```
string conn = @"DSN=database;UID=user;PWD=password;LONGDATACOMPAT=1;";
```